# Can't display more than one item from amazon product api response

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm fetching top selling items for a particular browseNodeId. The xml response has 10 items but when I print/display the information it shows only one. Please help.

My request array is:

```
    $params = array(
    "Service" => "AWSECommerceService",
    "Operation" => "BrowseNodeLookup",
    "AWSAccessKeyId" => "",
    "AssociateTag" => "",
    "BrowseNodeId" => "6386372011",
    "ResponseGroup" => "TopSellers"
);
```

(I removed my ids on purpose)

and this is how I'm parsing xml response:

```
    $response = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    foreach($response->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode as $item)
    {
     $topItem = $item->TopItemSet->TopItem->Title;
     $itemURL = $item->TopItemSet->TopItem->DetailPageURL;
     $itemID = $item->TopItemSet->TopItem->ASIN;


    $results .= "<tr><td><a href=\"$itemURL\">$topItem</a></td><td>$itemID</td></tr>";
  }
```

later on I'm simply printing '$results' using echo command. This approach is working with all other requesting/responses i.e. I'm getting & displaying 10 items without any problem. I can't find any error. Please help, I want to display 10 items not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the XML Object into array using this

```
$response = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$json_string = json_encode($response);
$result = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
```

And then access the elements using *array['key']* syntax.

Comment: Hey thanks but It didn't work. Earlier the xml response had desired data but using this method it doesn't get anything in return. Therefore I've changed my approach and using javaScript now.